# visualising data in Euclidean space rather than on a map

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I understand that Fusion Tables is great for visualising data on a map but how do I go about visualising data in a Euclidean space using Cartesian coordinates rather than latitude and longitude.  For example, data about the contents of shipping containers on a ship where latitude and longitude would not be appropriate and a position relative to an origin would be much easier to assign.

I have looked through the Help pages for Fusion Tables but they all deal with data on maps

Comment: FYI - Fusion Tables will be shut down on December 3, 2019 (probably isn't a good choice for new development)

Comment: So I have discovered!  It would be nice if Google updated their pages telling you how wonderful Fusion Tables are with this gem of information :(